# Elasticsearch mongo-connector KeyError _id

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch

I'm using mongo-connector to sync data from mongoDB replicaSet with elast2-doc-manager as Doc Manager.

I'm running mongo-connector as:

```
$mongo-connector --auto-commit-interval=5 --verbose -m 127.0.0.1:27017 -t localhost:9200 -d elastic2_doc_manager --namespace-set=db.collection1,db.collection2 --fields=f1,f2,f3
```

At some point I get this exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):  
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 551, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 85, in wrapped
    func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/oplog_manager.py", line 261, in run
    docman.upsert(doc, ns, timestamp)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/util.py", line 32, in wrapped
    return f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic2_doc_manager.py", line 150, in upsert
    doc_id = u(doc.pop("_id"))
```

I've added a try/except wrapping the method `File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mongo_connector/doc_managers/elastic2_doc_manager.py" Line 148` to print the problematic document in case of exception.

Somehow the `_id` is missing from the printed doc. But if I query mongo directly from interactive cmd I can fetch the same document, and the `_id` key is present.

So I don't know why `mongo-connector/elastic2_doc_manager` is not seeing the `_id` property for some documents.

Answer (score 0):

Mongo-connector, for whatever reason, seems to remove the `_id` from your document. In turn however the string representation of the ObjectId from mongodb is stored as the _id in elasticsearch. It still there however its not in the document, or as elasticsearch would refer to it the "source".

Take a look at a query result, it'll be structured something like this:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 3,
    "successful" : 3,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 135513,
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "5294b93e6c255bb82d0000c0", <-- ID from mongodb
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{
        "some": "data",
        "my": "document"
      },
      {
      "_index" : "myIndex",
      "_type" : "myType",
      "_id" : "5294b93e6c255bb82d0000de", <-- ID from mongodb
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_source":{
        "some": "data2",
        "my": "document2"
      }
    }]
  }
}
```

I was under the impression that mongo-connector did this on purpose. To just store the _id in the appropriate ES field, though I don't see a reason to also remove the _id from the `_source` of the document as well. However I've noticed the lack of id's on documents in ES while using the elastic_doc_manager(v1).

Answer (score 0):

Run mongo-connector -c config.json 
and here is the sample file for [config.json](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/blob/master/config.json) and there you can configure _id correctly.

And define in .json file -

```
"docManagers": [
    {
        "docManager": "elastic2_doc_manager",
        "__targetURL": "localhost:9200",
        "bulkSize": 5000,
        "uniqueKey": "_id",
        "__autoCommitInterval": null,
        "args": {
        "aws": {
            "region_name": "your-choice"
    }
  }
```